# Is there a way to use an array as inputId for a Shiny element?

Tags: r, shiny

I need a variable amount of textboxinputs. Currently I create the inputs in a loop,

```
textInput(paste0("text", i))
```

Then I can access them using

```
input$text1, input$text2, input$text3, ...
```

but I cannot use these explicit expressions in a loop. I tried with ensym and get(eval(...)) but it did not work.
Is there a way to define the inputIds of each textInput in an array, i.e. something like textInput("text[i]"))?

Here is a simplified example:

app.R

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput(paste0("textin1"), label = NULL, value = 1),
  textInput(paste0("textin2"), label = NULL, value = 2),
  textInput(paste0("textin3"), label = NULL, value = 3),
  verbatimTextOutput("textout1"),
  verbatimTextOutput("textout2"),
  verbatimTextOutput("textout3")
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$textout1 <- renderText({input$textin1})
  output$textout2 <- renderText({input$textin2})
  output$textout3 <- renderText({input$textin3})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Is there a way to assign the inputs and outputs by an array, i.e. textin[i] instead of textin1, textin2, ...

Comment: Can you provide `ui` and `server` code required for the question to be completely reproducible along with necessary data if required?

Comment: You can do `input[[paste0("text", i)]]`.

Comment: That did the trick, you saved my day again!